# Where are neurodes on Earth?

Tags: warframe

I am MR4 and want to craft the Hek, as it becomes really powerful with the 'Scattered Justice' mod. However, to do so, I need 1-2 more neurodes. Unfortunately, when I run Earth missions, I seem to not be able to find any neuroptic masses or chests that contain neurodes. So, are there any specific missions on Earth that grant neurodes, or am I just having bad luck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neurodes can drop from any node in Earth. However, they are fairly rare, and may take multiple attempts. You can run endless missions such as defense, survival, interception, or excavation until you get the resources or can't continue. If you do this, it's recommended that you bring a frame such as Nekros or Hydroid with the Pilfering Swarm augment to increase drop rates. Bosses also have very high drop rates of rare resources, and you can probably get what you need in a couple of runs. This has the added advantage of helping you get the parts you need for Hydroid, who will be useful in farming rare resources in the future. The boss of earth can unfortunately be rather difficult and annoying, but given that you only need a couple neurodes it shouldn't be terrible, especially if you get some help either in a public group or from recruiting chat.

Comment: +1, but worth noting that as far as bosses go, earth is kind of an outlier with a disproportionately difficult boss, for the planet level.  Also, Survival is another good endless mission type for farming.

Comment: @JohntheGreen It's not the only one.  The boss of Europa (The Raptors) are so difficult that they actually removed them from the junction requirements because it was stopping new player progression.

Comment: @Powerlord Fair, but the Raptor wasn't designed to require farming 2 planets later just for the entry key, like Vay Hek used to.  For a while, Vay Hek was literally impossible to do until you were well beyond his planet.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [guide](https://warframeblog.com/warframe-neurodes-farming/) you should go in Tikal on Earth and you will get 4-5 neurodes every 15-20 minutes. I tried and I only got 2 neurodes probably because I did this mission without Nekros(I still don't have him)

Answer (score 0):

In the earth you go to the only mission that there is of excavation and there you are a while and you take at least 1 neurode at a time, I recommend you go with a Nekros to increase the possibilities

Comment: Do you know how long approximately you have to stay there (as in, how much cryotic or how many excavations)?